# how to get highest version of record from a list

Tags: java

I have nearly 500 file. each file has nearly 5 version or 10 version with the same name. each file distinguish start with file name followed by semicolon then version number.

example:

> Test.pdf;1
>   Test.pdf;2 
>   Test.pdf;3

so i am getting list of file by doing this:

```
    File file = new File(Path + "\\");
    File[] fileList = file.listFiles();

    List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        String name=fileList[i].getName();

        if(name.contains(".pdf")||name.contains(".excel")){
            namesList.add(name);

        }

    for (int i = 0; i < namesList.size(); i++) {
        String name = namesList.get(i);

   }
```

How to get only highest version file i.e test.pdf;3

Comment: are `Test.pdf;1 Test.pdf;2 Test.pdf;3` real file names (in filesystem) or you have some kind of csv?

Comment: substring filename with ;. you will get version and filename. store it in hashmap. replace value in map if older version is less than new version.

Comment: can u show me any example for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code shown below:

```
String[] files = {"test.pdf;3","test.pdf;1","differentTest.pdf;2","test.pdf;5","test.pdf;4", "test.excel;3","test.excel;1","test.excel;6","test.excel;5","test.excel;4"};

HashMap <String, Integer> newestFiles = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

for (String currentString : files) {
    String currentFileName = currentString.split(";")[0];
    Integer currentFileVersion = Integer.parseInt(currentString.split(";")[1]);

    if (newestFiles.containsKey(currentFileName)) {
        if (newestFiles.get(currentFileName) < currentFileVersion) {
            newestFiles.put(currentFileName, currentFileVersion);
        }
    }
    else {
        newestFiles.put(currentFileName, currentFileVersion);
    }
}

for (Entry<String, Integer> maxValue : newestFiles.entrySet()) {

    String result = new StringBuilder("Max version of file: ").append(maxValue.getKey()).append(" is: ").append( maxValue.getValue()).toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Result:

```
Max version of file: test.excel is: 6
Max version of file: test.pdf is: 5
Max version of file: differentTest.pdf is: 2
```

What is done here:

1. For every file get its name and version - using splitting.
2. Then check if you already processed files with that name (all processed are stored in newestFiles Map).
3. If it was not processed add it to the Map with current file
   version (in `else` statement).
4. If it was processed check if
   current version is bigger. If it is, substitute the file in the map.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Map` to map each file name to a version. Iterate over your file names extract the name part and the version part and then compare the version with a previously saved one in the map. If there is no version for a name in the map then put the actual version in the Map as the highest.

You could try something like this:

```
@Test
public void listHighestVersion() {
    String[] fileNames = {
        "Test.pdf;1", "Test.pdf;2", "Test.pdf;3",
        "Test.excel;1", "Test.excel;4", "Test.excel;3",
    };

    Map<String, Integer> fileVersionMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(String fileNameWithVersion : fileNames) {
        String[] split = fileNameWithVersion.split(";", 2);
        if(split.length > 1) {
            String fileName = split[0];
            Integer fileVersion;
            try {
                fileVersion = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                fileVersion = 0;
            }
            Integer version = fileVersionMap.get(fileName);
            if(version == null || fileVersion > version) {
                fileVersionMap.put(fileName, fileVersion);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fileVersionMap);
}
```

output is:

```
{Test.excel=4, Test.pdf=3}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy let me try with it

Comment: @Mayur, You're welcome. Please note that you should handle Exceptions as you need, for example if there is no version appended to a file or if the version part is not a valid integer, in the code above it just defaults to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class say `FileDetail` with 2 attributs i.e. String `fileName` and integer `version` as attributes.
2. create `List<FileDetail>` as you are creating `namesList`
3. Implement `comparable` or `comparator` for class `FileDetail` and implement your sorting logic.